# Monitor status of internet connection

Tags: c#, wpf, http, monitoring, network-monitoring

I try to implement (in **WPF**, *C#*) `Ellipse` control which changes its colour depending on connection to [google.com](http://www.google.com/). If there is connection with *Google*, ellipse is green; else it's red.

I coded it this way:

XAML code

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <l:InternetConnectionToBrushConverter x:Key="InternetConnectionConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StatusBar Height="23" Name="statusBar1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <Label Content="Google connection:" Name="label1" FontSize="10" Padding="3" />
            <Ellipse Name="ellipse1" Stroke="Black" Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Converter={StaticResource InternetConnectionConverter}}" Margin="0,4,0,0" />
        </StatusBar>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

and C# behind-code (value converter and function checking connection):

```cs
public class InternetConnectionToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(Brush))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a Brush!");

        return CheckConnection("http://www.google.com/") == true ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks connection to specified URL. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="URL"></param>
    /// <returns><b>True</b> if there is connection. Else <b>false</b>.</returns>
    private bool CheckConnection(String URL)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Timeout = 15000;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK ? true : false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

It works well but there are 2 problems:

1. it takes some time to check connection, so I think I should be doing it in new thread (if I'm wrong, please tell me why)
2. what's more important - it checks connection with [Google](http://www.google.com/) only once, when program starts running (despite I use binding, so I expect that there would be constant connection monitoring)

How should I solve this? 
I want to have constant connection monitoring, so that when I disconnect internet connection, `Ellipse` control will change its colour.

Comment: Do you have controller class or some other container of logic? You could add timer there and initiate checking in a new thread each time timer ticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change your architecture a bit.
You can not use threading in an `IValueConverter` to avoid locking the UI. You still need to wait for the thread to complete before returning from the `IValueConverter`.

You need to create a `HasConnection` property to bind the ellipse color to. You can then run the connection check in another thread. Preferably by using the `BackgroundWorker`. The `HasConnection` property should be updated once the check is complete. You can then use a timer and check your connection periodically and update the `HasConnection` after each check.

**Edit**
You can also monitor the [`NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) event to find out when local network connection goes up or down. However of you want to ensure that you can actually connect to your target you should keep your old `CheckConnection`, but call `CheckConnection` on startup, when the network availability changes and periodically on a timer.

Comment: I don't get it. I'll write `HasConnection` property in which I'll start `BackgroundWorker` or `Task` checking connection with Google. What's more I should use `DispatchetTimer` but what for? If I'll bind `HasConnection` property (returning `bool`) to the ellipse colour via value converter. I can't see the idea how it should actually work.

Comment: No, start the BackgroundWorker or task from outside the view model, when you start the application. Update the property on the view model when the BackgroundWorker completes.

Answer (score 0):

Use background worker to monitor in the background and ReportProgress to get the current status

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    bool connected = false;
    string url = "https://www.google.com/";

    while (!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Timeout = 15000;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            connected = (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10, connected);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            e.Cancel = true;
            e.Result = "cancelled";

            //return false;
        }
    }
    e.Result = connected;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.tbResult.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.UserState.ToString());
}
```